# Postgresql partitions based on row create timestamp

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am trying to create partitioned table in PostgreSQL using partition by range (row_create_tmst). row_create_tmst data type - timestamp with timezone.

I was able to define partitions for specific days as below:

CREATE TABLE source_record_Apr10 PARTITION OF source_record_new
FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-04-10T00:00:00') TO ('2023-04-10T23:59:59');

Partitions are created but when I try to insert data into partitioned table from table with exact same columns with same data types I am getting below error:

insert into source_record_new
(select * from source_record where row_created_tmst between '2023-04-10 00:00:00.000+00' and '2023-04-10 23:59:59.999+00')

ERROR: column "row_modified_tmst" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying
LINE 3: (select * from midas_user.staging_source_record where row_c...

Comment: Please check the ddl for midas_user.staging_source_record, the error message states that text is used

Comment: Also, the upper partition limit should be `'2023-04-11T00:00:00'`.